# Memory leak using QListView

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, qlistview

I'm working on an applications launcher and decided to use a QListView to display the Items. I wrote a Model and an ItemDelegate but it seems to be wasting memory somewhere I can't find.
The issue is that even scrolling on the app list makes my program to consume more and more memory.
I think it is related to the way I paint but I cant see where the mistake is.

Paint method on the QStyledItemDelegate

```
void DashViewItemDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const {
    QString name = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    QIcon icon = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DecorationRole).value<QIcon>();
    QRect iconRect = QRect(option.rect.x() + 10, option.rect.y(), option.rect.width() - 20, option.rect.height() - 43);
    QRect textRect = QRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y() + 60, option.rect.width(), option.rect.height() - 60);

    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());

    icon.paint(painter, iconRect, Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignTop);

    QTextLayout textLayout(name);
    textLayout.setFont(option.font);
    int widthUsed = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
    textLayout.beginLayout();

    while (++lineCount < 3) { 
        QTextLine line = textLayout.createLine();
        if (!line.isValid())
            break;

    line.setLineWidth(option.rect.width());
    widthUsed += line.naturalTextWidth();
}
    textLayout.endLayout();

    widthUsed += option.rect.width();

    QString newText = painter->fontMetrics().elidedText(name, Qt::ElideRight, widthUsed);
    painter->drawText(textRect, Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignTop | Qt::TextWordWrap , newText);

    painter->save();
}
```

help will be really appreciated

Comment: Can you show your use of this function?  Are you calling painter->end() or painter->restore() at some point?

Comment: I only set this itemdelegate to the view and it paints as I want. view->setItemDelegate(new DashViewItemDelegate());

Comment: What happens if you remove `painter->save();`?

Comment: still works, but memory usage stills growing when I do scroll or change the model of the view

Comment: well now I removed my QStyledItemDelegate and realized that this weird thing happens with the standard Qt's QStyledItemDelegate. Could this problem be related to the BatchSize?

Comment: I changed the LayoutMode to SinglePass and the memory leak is reduced, but still there. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Are you sure it's a memory leak and not just the way your OS handles memory?

Comment: seems to be leaking somewhere else. when I removed the save() It got better but still not working completely fine.